# MongooseError: Operation `orders.deleteMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when I run my app with `npm run seeder`
then I have face this error
I have checked my database connection carefully, it's ok.
also, I have checked my ordermodels file it's also ok. I have used MongoDB compass there is nothing problem. I don't know why showing `buffering timed out`.

```
MongooseError: Operation `orders.deleteMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

> seeder.js

```
    import mongoose from "mongoose";
    import dotenv from "dotenv";
    import colors from "colors";
    import users from "./data/users.js";
    import products from "./data/products.js";
    import User from "./models/userModel.js";
    import Product from "./models/productModel.js";
    import Order from "./models/orderModel.js";
    import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
    
    dotenv.config();
    connectDB();
    
    const importData = async () => {
      try {
        await Order.deleteMany();
        await Product.deleteMany();
        await User.deleteMany();
    
        const createUsers = await User.insertMany(users);
        const adminUser = createUsers[0]._id;
        const sampleProducts = products.map((product) => {
          return { ...product, user: adminUser };
        });
        await Product.insertMany(sampleProducts);
    
        console.log("Data Imported".green.inverse);
        process.exit();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`${error}`.red.inverse);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    };
    
    const DeleteData = async () => {
      try {
        await Order.deleteMany();
        await Product.deleteMany();
        await User.deleteMany();
    
        console.log("Data Deleted".red.inverse);
        process.exit();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`${error}`.red.inverse);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    };
    
    if (process.argv[2] === "-d") {
      DeleteData();
    } else {
      importData();
    }
```

Comment: can you show us the connectDB()  function ?  it may be a problem of connection with mongoose

Comment: Thank you, now I have solved my problem, actually, there was a network connection problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have the same issue and I just did a research and I find that your MongoDB are trying to execute the function `User.deleteMany()` before the database is connected.

just put an await before `connectDB()`;

```
await connectDB();
```

Answer (score 4):

const importData = async () => {

try {

```
await connectDB();

await Category.collection.deleteMany({});

await Category.insertMany(categoryData);

console.log('Success ');
```

} catch (error) {

```
console.log('error in processing data ', error);
```

}

};

importData();

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue, but I managed to resolve it.

So in `package.json`, in the `scripts` section I've added:

```
"data:import": "node backend/seeder",
"data:destroy": "node backend/seeder -d",
```

Then:

```
npm run data:import
```

After trying a couple of times, I've got `Data Imported` message in the console.

Note: I haven't uninstalled any node_modules.

Answer (score 2):

use following code for connect to mongodb

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true })
```

after that you should removing the node_module folder and  all .json files and reinstalling the mongoose and use `npm update`

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Did this solve the OP's issue?  If so, please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Why and how is this a solution?

Answer (score 2):

you can move connectDB() to importData() and deleteData(). and add **await** before connectDB(). like this:

```
const importData = async () => {
    try {
        await connectDB();
        //...
    }
}
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Write useFindAndModify:true, in mongoose.connect(DB,{}) , because by default it is false and you are trying to delete something form database.
So, write it like this

```
mongoose.connect(DB,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useFindAndModify:true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after some research I found one solution.

I just rename the :

```
DB_LOCAL_URI = mongodb://localhost:27017
```

To:

```
DB_LOCAL_URI = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

Great it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is very Simple, I tried every suggestion and answer to this question on this topic. But the problem didn't go away.
It is true that the connection was not able to establish with the database.

I moved .env file to parent folder where dotenv package is installed. Every functionality will run after this. I hope this answer have helped you.
Happy Coding.)