# Mongoose deleteMany() timing out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and my internet connection is slow. Most of the time when running the code I'm getting the following error:

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.deleteMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

The line is:

```
await User.deleteMany({})
```

Please note that the same code is working sometimes but when the internet isn't great it's not so I think that it simply needs more time but I cannot figure out how to change the timeout for `deleteMany()`

I tried the following:

```
await User.deleteMany({}).maxTimeMS(50000)
```

but I'm still getting the same error.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongooseError: Operation \`orders.deleteMany()\` buffering timed out after 10000ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599791/mongooseerror-operation-orders-deletemany-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms)

Comment: @turivishal Thank you for your comment. I already have an await before the connection, and as I mentioned in the post the error only occurs when the internet is unstable.

Comment: With the 50000ms you get same errormessage referring to 10000ms?

Comment: @Ralle thank you for your comment. Yes, and it seems about the same time until getting the message. I have also tried extreme cases like 500,000 still no difference in message or wait time.